# Multiple models and multiple serializer in single response in DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-queryset

- I'm creating a search functionality that returns all model fields like - users, posts, hashtags, images, and videos.
- I'm trying to create multiple queryset with their multiple serializers to return in a single response.

## this is my expected response result.

```
{
searchresults{
        posts[

        ],images[
                    
    
            
        
        ],videos[
                    
            
        
        ],user[
                
                
        ]
    }
}
```

- I tried many methods to do this, but the response was unsuccessful.
- I also tried that one but that required relationship.

```
class HashTagResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HashtagName
        fields = ["hashtag",]
    
    def get_hashtag(self, obj):
        ...

class UserFollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hashtag = HashTagResponseSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

   class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['user_uuid', 'post_language', "username", "display_name",
                    "profile_picture", "hashtag "]
```

Comment: are you aware of `serializerMethodField`

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. but this is not working, if the first sterilizer model finds value for its working if not found it's not working so the other is skip that time.